# How to call Interface function in go-gin?

Tags: go, interface, go-gin

This is repository + controller

```
package brand

import (
    "path/to/models"
    "gorm.io/gorm"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type ResponseBrand struct {
    Items      []models.MasterBrand `json:"items"`
    TotalCount int                  `json:"total"`
}

type Repository interface {
    GetAll() (ResponseBrand, error)
}

type DBRepo struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}


func (repo *DBRepo) GetAll() (ResponseBrand, error) {
    var response ResponseBrand
    var brands []models.MasterBrand

    repo.db.Find(&brands)

    response.Items = brands
    response.TotalCount = len(brands)

    return response, nil
}

func list(c *gin.Context) {
    // this is an error
    res, _ := Repository.GetAll()
}
```

This for routing group

```
func ApplyRoutes(r *gin.RouterGroup) {
    brand := r.Group("/brand") {
        brand.GET("/", list)
    }
}
```

I try to implement repository in my project, but still stuck to call **Repository.GetAll()** in our controller function **list**. i use gin & gorm for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface is just a set of method signatures that type must have in order to implement that particular interface. So you can't call interface.

In your example code `DBRepo` is supposed to implement `Repository` interface and function `list()` is a function that allows to list contents of any type that implements `Repository`. In to do so obviously `list()` needs to know which instance of `Repository`-like type to list - e.g. receive it as an argument. Like this:

```golang
func list(ctx *gin.Context, repo Repository) {
    // here call GetAll() which MUST exist on all types passed (otherwise they don't
    // implement Repository interface
    res, _ := repo.GetAll()
    // ...
}
```

Now `gin` wouldn't be able to take modified list as a router function because signature of such is just `(ctx *gin.Context)` but you can use anonymous function and wrap your Repository-aware `list()` in it.

```golang
func ApplyRoutes(repo Repository, r *gin.RouterGroup) {
    brand := r.Group("/brand") {
        brand.GET("/", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
            list(repo)
        })
    }
}
```

Also your `ApplyRoutes()` function needs to know on which Repository routes should operate - I added it here as argument for simplicity, other elegant solution would be to wrap entire controller in type and obtain the `Repository` instance as a field of receiver.

Answer (score 0):

```
func ApplyRoutes(repo Repository, r *gin.RouterGroup) {
brand := r.Group("/brand") {
    brand.GET("/", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        list(ctx, repo)
    })
}}
```

If not, this might work.